# How to save highscores in javascript game?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Ok so i made a JavaScript snake game and i want to add option "scores" that shows top 10 players with their name and score. The idea was, when game over,to make an object that contains name and score and store it into an array, and then store that array in localStorage. It prints out just 1 player, it has something to do with variable "dead" and because page needs to be reloaded everytime. Any advice?

```
var players = [];
function igrac(ime,bodovi){
    this.ime=ime;
    this.bodovi=bodovi;
}
// game over
    if ( snakeX < box || snakeX>17*box || snakeY<3*box || snakeY>17*box || collision(newHead,snake)){
        dead.play();
        clearInterval(game);
        var dead= new igrac(prompt("Unesite ime da zapamtite skor:","Vase ime"),score);
        players.unshift(dead);
        localStorage.setItem("niz",JSON.stringify(players)); 
        window.location.href="menu.html";

    }
var nesto=localStorage.getItem("niz");
var players2=JSON.parse(nesto);

players2.sort(function(a,b){
    return b.bodovi-a.bodovi;
})
for( var i in players2){
    document.write(players2[i].ime + "--------------" + players2[i].bodovi);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are saving to `localStorage`, but not reading from it. You set `var players = [];` on page load, but you need to read the previous scores instead:

```
var players = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("niz"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Also I made a mistake, there's dead audio file and also dead variable, change that and it works fine ..